# Prove$(2,x^2+x+1)$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I tried : From the third isomorphism theorem we have $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(2,x^2+x+1)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2)}{(2,x^2+x+1)/(2)}$, if we can prove 1: $(2,x^2+x+1)/(2) \cong ( \overline {x^2+x+1}) $ and 2: $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2)}{(2,x^2+x+1)/(2)} \cong  \frac{\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]}{(\overline {x^2+x+1})}$, then because $\overline {x^2+x+1} $ has no root in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x] $ so it is irreducible and they are fields, then we are done. I can prove the second assertion, but I can’t prove the first assertion. I don’t know if this is a right proof direction. Could someone help me, thank you.

Comment: This is correct, what is your question precisely?

Comment: I have two questions.. 1: how to prove the first assertion     2:  I proved the second assertion by definition: find a map and prove the map is an isomorphism. Is there a theorem we can apply to simplify the proof of this isomorphism? (I know an exercise :$G_1 \cong G_2$ and $H_1 \cong H_2$ , then $G_1/H_1$ and $G_2/H_2$ are not necessarily isomorphic. So we must prove this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this. 
$\mathbb Z[x]/(2) \cong (\mathbb Z/2) [x]$ 
The same isomorphism takes $\frac {(2, x²+x+1) }{(2)}$ to $(x²+x+1) $ in $\mathbb Z/2[x]$  so $\mathbb Z[x]/(2, x²+x+1) \cong \mathbb Z/2[x]/(x²+x+1) $ . 
Here I am using if $A\cong B$ and the isomorphism takes $I$ to $J$ then it induces an isomorphism $A/I \cong B/J$ .

Comment: Thank you, so actually we don’t need to prove $(2,x^2+x+1)/(2) \cong ( \overline {x^2+x+1}) $?

Comment: I essentially proved that but the RHS is an ideal in $\mathbb Z_2[x]$ not in $\mathbb Z[x]/(2) $

Answer (score 2):

You asked the first assertion i.e., $ (2,x^2+x+1)/(2) \cong (x^2+x+1) \mod 2$.

It is clear that $(2,x^2+x+1)/(2)=2c+(x^2+x+1)d+(2), \ c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$.

As $2c \in (2)$, we get $(2,x^2+x+1)/(2) \cong (x^2+x+1) \mod 2$.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a theorem we can apply to simplify the proof of this isomorphism? (The second assertion, my comment on this question )

Comment: @user725757,well, if you are talking about this first assertion, you just consider the $\text{reduction map modulo}$ $2$ , which will give the isomorphism.

Comment: Sorry I typed it wrong, I mean the second assertion. I think Nabakumar Bhattacharya’s method is ok.

Comment: @user725757,yes it is ok

Answer (score 2):

It is well-known that the maximal ideals of $\Bbb Z[z]$ are of the form $(p, f(x))$ where $p \in \Bbb Z$ is a prime and $f(x) \in \Bbb Z[x]$ is irreducible mod $p$.  See for example
https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/voloch/Homework/zx.pdf.  We apply this result to the present problem, with $p = 2$ and

$f(x) = x^2 + x + 1; \tag 1$

since

$\deg f(x) = 2, \tag 2$

$f(x)$ is reducible modulo $p = 2$ if and only if it has a zero in

$\Bbb Z \mod 2 = \Bbb Z_2, \tag 3$

but it is easily seen that this is not so, *via* direct evaluation of $f(x)$ in $\Bbb Z_2$:

$f(0) = 0^2 + 0 + 1 = 1 \mod 2,  \tag 4$

$f(1) = 1^2 + 1 + 1 = 1 + 1 + 1 = 1 \mod 2; \tag 5$

therefore $f(x)$ is irreducible modulo $2$, and the cited theorem may then be invoked to conclude that $(2, x^2 + x + 1)$ is maximal in $\Bbb Z_[x]$.

Comment: It is a nice answer for the OP